# how to transfer item(image,string) by segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, cloudkit

**When i click the cell.**
I want to transfer the image and string in  chosen's cell by segue.
I try to use "func prepareforsegue".
And i don't know how to write.
Please help me.

Here's the tableview func:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DiscoverTableViewCell

    //set cell
    let restaurant = restaurants[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurant.objectForKey("name") as? String
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurant.objectForKey("type") as? String
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurant.objectForKey("location") as? String

    //set default image
    cell.bgImageView.image = nil

    //check image in chche or not
    if let imageFileUrl = imageCache.objectForKey(restaurant.recordID) as? NSURL {
        //get image from cache
        print("Get image from cache")
        cell.bgImageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageFileUrl)!)
    }else {      
    //get data from cloudkit in background
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let fetchRecordsImageOperation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs:[restaurant.recordID])
    fetchRecordsImageOperation.desiredKeys = ["image"]
    fetchRecordsImageOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh

    fetchRecordsImageOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { (record:CKRecord?, recordID:CKRecordID?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            print("Fail to get restaurant image: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let restaurantRecord = record {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
                if let imageAsset = restaurantRecord.objectForKey("image") as? CKAsset {
                    cell.bgImageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageAsset.fileURL)!)

                    // Add the image URL to cache
                    self.imageCache.setObject(imageAsset.fileURL, forKey: restaurant.recordID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    publicDatabase.addOperation(fetchRecordsImageOperation)
  }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Show only the code that's relevant (that means `prepareForSegue` and describing the exact contents of your `CKRecord`).

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? on prepareForSegue it seems that you are in the right track to what you want to accomplish. Can you specify what type is restaurantImage? Is it an UIImage or NSData? I would parse the NSData alone and then create the UIImage on the ViewDidLoad of the DiscoverDetailViewController.

Comment: sorry guys,i try to edit my post,but it shows wrongs all the time

Comment: i'm trying to say,
i use cloudkit to get data in this viewcontroller,
and i want to use segue to transfer image to another viewcontroller
i don't kown how to write in "func prepareForSegue"

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with CloudKit? Your question only has to do with passing an image from one controller to another through the segue? If so, please remove all of the irrelevant code from your question and fully explain what exact issue you are having passing the image through the segue.

Comment: @rmaddy  
is this okay?

Comment: No. None of the code in your question now has anything to do with performing a segue.

Comment: @rmaddy yes,there's none of code about segue,but i mean to,i set segue already.but i don't know how to write the code in prepare func that i can pass the item to another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if @Anand's answer can not help you, try this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // sender is your Cell, it includes the image and string, 
    // pass them to next view controller is ok,
    // use them in SecondViewController's viewDidLoad() is ok.
    let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
    secondViewController.image = cell.imageView?.image
    secondViewController.text = cell.textLabel?.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can pass image with segue this way

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == showPhotoSegueIdentifier {
            if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
                let url = photos[indexPath.item]
                if let _ = cache.objectForKey(url) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == showPhotoSegueIdentifier {
            if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
                let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoViewController
                let url = photos[indexPath.item]

                controller.photo = cache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
            }
        }
    }
```

### And in Second view you can use this code for show image

```
import UIKit

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView?
    var photo: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imageView?.image = photo
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView?.image = photo
    }

    @IBAction func dismiss(sender: AnyObject!) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```